# Oracle Linux R6 Install Error

Tags: rhel, system-installation, oracle-linux, installer-anaconda

My Oracle Linux R6 x64 won't install. After normal install it's just blank screen. After basic video driver options install stuck on "Waiting for hardware to initialize...". Tried with different options runs only with noprobe but no drivers at all (understandably). Is there any way to run it normally?

Spcecs:
Asus Rampage Extreme IV Extreme - Newest BIOS,
Intel i7 4930K,
Graphics: Geforce 210

Comment: Try a newer version? Try another RHEL clone, like CentOS? Check out with (a LiveCD for) a related distribution, like Fedora? Perhaps some of those alternatives give you more than a blank screen, and you can start debugging.

Comment: Check the install media, I've had hangs due to bad media. Run tests on the machine, e.g. `memtest`.

Comment: OEL is the newest, Fedora/CentOS/openSuse freezed during whether "waiting for hardware to initialize..." or "starting udev..." All media was without errors. Ubuntu also fails to install http://askubuntu.com/questions/430377/cant-install-ubuntu-on-an-asus-rampage-extreme-iv

Comment: Any signs of life at all? I.e., disk LED, reacts to BlockNum or such for keyboard LEDs? Again, please run hardware diagnostics. Try text-only install. At least Fedora has an option of "basic graphics driver install" or similar, check for that.